# Como efetuar busca com uma variável de texto contendo apóstrofos?

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Problema**

Ao efetuar pesquisas com textos contendo apóstrofos, não são encontrados resultados.

**Execução**

```
DECLARE @cidade NVARCHAR(50) 

SELECT @cidade = cidade FROM tabela_A WHERE id = xv

SELECT campo FROM tabela_B WHERE cidade = @cidade
```

O exemplo acima retorna o resultado da tabela_A com a cidade *OLHO D'AGUA DO CASADO*, porém ao efetuar a pesquisa na tabela_B ela não me retorna nada.

Ao efetuar a busca "manualmente", informando `cidade = "OLHO D'AGUA DO CASADO"` o resultado é conforme o esperado.

**Tentativas**

Atribuindo o valor da cidade a uma variável, tentei utilizar as funções `QUOTENAME` e `REPLACE`, porém sem sucesso.

Comment: Marcelo, a variável @cidade necessita ser unicode? É que, no caso de constantes Unicode, é necessário ficar atento ao COLLATE dos objetos envolvidos.

Comment: Sim, necessita, @J.D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Marcelo, para atribuir OLHO D'AGUA DO CASADO a uma variável, você pode utilizar algumas formas de definir [constantes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms179899.aspx), dentre as quais transcrevo duas:

```
-- código #1 -- apóstrofo como delimitador de constante
declare @cidade nvarchar(200);
set @cidade= N'OLHO D''AGUA DO CASADO';
go
```

Atento que em D''AGUA não há uma aspas mas sim dois apóstrofos.

Já "OLHO D'AGUA DO CASADO", delimitado por aspas, somente será reconhecido como constante caso QUOTED_IDENTIFIER esteja OFF.

```
-- código #2 -- aspas como delimitador de constante
set QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF;
declare @cidade nvarchar(200);
set @cidade= "OLHO D'AGUA DO CASADO";
go
```

---

A pesquisa na tabela_B, a partir de uma variável, pode então ser feita da seguinte forma:

```
-- código #3
declare @cidade nvarchar(200);
set @cidade= N'OLHO D''AGUA DO CASADO';

SELECT campo 
  from tabela_B
  where cidade = @cidade;
```

---

O apóstrofo é um sinal de pontuação que tem como função indicar a supressão de letras numa palavra, como Santa Bárbara d’Oeste (d*o* Oeste). A esta supressão dá-se o nome de *elisão*. Nos computadores normalmente utilizamos um símbolo gráfico parecido, que é o ápice.
Ápice:  **'**
Apóstrofo (abre e fecha): **‘ ’**
Aspas (abre e fecha): **“ ”**

Comment: @MarcelodeAndrade - Marcelo, a solução proposta atendeu? Se ainda não: (1) como está definido o agrupamento (COLLATE) da instância e do banco de dados? (2) Como estão declaradas as colunas cidade nas tabelas tabela_A e tabela_B?